# Sending JSON data containing a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an object, example:

```
var object = { name: "lalala", alert: function(){ alert(this.name)} }
```

I want send this to my server (nodejs+express) as a JSON, but I am getting this parser error, how I can do this?

JSON example:

```
{ "name": "lalala", "alert": "function"(){ "alert"("this.name") } }
```

Comment: You can't send a funtion as value in json

Comment: That won't be valid json. The best thing you could do is to put your function in a string and evaluate that, but it isn't something your really should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not a valid JSON object. You can't have a function inside of a JSON. You are working with a JavaScript Object instead. Take a look at the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) to learn exactly what is valid for JSON.

---

If you *really* wanted to pass that data to your server, you would have to convert the value to a string and then eval (*shudder*) it at a later stage to get back the underlying function.

Answer (score 0):

This totally odd and **not proper way of doing a JSON**

You **can't have a function inside a JSON object**,

That why you got **parser error**...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way. Send the value of the alert in the json, and then run the alert function when the value is received at the other end.

```
var object = { name: "lalala", alert: "lalala"}

alert(object.alert);
```

Edit: In fact all you would need is

```
var object = { name: "lalala"}
```

When response received:

```
alert(object.name);
```

Comment: Is this will really works?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following trick.

```
var c = { "s" : "sss", "alert" : "alert(c.s)"}
eval(c.alert);
```

You will get your alert. However it's not going to fly with something like:

```
eval("function(){alert(c.s);}")
```